# Is there a need to set the parameters again when updating a texture?

Tags: opengl, textures

Suppose that I'm developing the class [COpenGLControl here in code guru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c10975/Setting-Up-OpenGL-in-an-MFC-Control.htm) to use it for showing a 2D texture in an MFC CPictureControl. and after applying some filters on the image, I will update the texture to show the filtered image on the picture control.

I have set a rule for the clients of my class as follows:

Call function `setImageWidthHeightType` just first time of calling `OnTimer` and after setting `pImage`
`pImage` is the rastetr data that will be provided by another classes that have been developed using OpenCV and GDAL libraries
for the next calls of `OnTimer` and when updating `pImage` there's no need to call this function. If you do so, your client code slows down because the function `InitializeTextureObject()` is called in the `setImageWidthHeightType` function
For second and more calls of `OnTimer` you should call `updataTextureObject()` function after setting `pImage`. In the first call of `OnTimer` and before calling `setImageWidthHeightType`, the function `updataTextureObject()` should not be called and if so, the program will encounter an unhandled exception because there you still don't have any texture object to be updated.

any way I have used the following codes for the functions that are mentioned above:

**OpenGLControl.h**
allocate texture name which will be an `unsigned integer`

```
GLuint texture;
```

**OpenGLControl.cpp**
Generate just one texture and bind it to the target:

```
void COpenGLControl::InitializeTextureObject()
{
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);
    glEnable(target);
    glGenTextures(1,&texture);
    glBindTexture(target,texture);
    glTexParameteri(target,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(target,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(target,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(target,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_REPLACE);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
    glTexImage2D(target,level,internalformat,ImageWidth,ImageHeight,border,format,type,&pImage[0]);
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
}
```

the question that roses up is that
Is there a need to set the parameters again when updating texture because of using `wglMakeCurrent(NULL,NULL)` at the end of the function above?
In other words should I write the function `updataTextureObject()` as this:

```
void COpenGLControl::updataTextureObject()
{
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);
    glEnable(target);
    glBindTexture(target,texture);
    glTexParameteri(target,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(target,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(target,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(target,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_REPLACE);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);  
  glTexSubImage2D(target,level,xOffset,yOffset,ImageWidth,ImageHeight,format,type,&pImage[0]);
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
}
```

Or just as this:

```
void COpenGLControl::updataTextureObject()
{
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);  
    glTexSubImage2D(target,level,xOffset,yOffset,ImageWidth,ImageHeight,format,type,&pImage[0]);
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
}
```

What way is the correct one?

Comment: I'm sorry, your **random use of boldface** and `code formatting` is **making** `it hard` **to understand `what you're asking for`.**. Could you reformat this into a more legible form, where you, say, restrict your use of boldface to... say, maybe less than *half* of your words.

Comment: thanks @Nicol Bolas. I tried to reformat it. the italic text starting from the fifth line is the rule that I have set for the clients of the code and I have tried to write the name of member data and member functions of the class in `code format`. I have asked my question in **bold format** besides **OpenGLControl.h** and **OpenGLControl.cpp** are the declaration and definition of my class.

Comment: My main point is that we can find your question just fine without you putting it in bold face. We aren't invalids or mentally deficient; we know what a question mark means.

Comment: ok then I will take your advice for next times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `wglMakeCurrent (NULL, NULL);` will not cause you to lose any state. What it *will* do is make any OpenGL call in the thread where you did this an invalid operation (until you make a device + render context current again).

So if you were to try to setup state during a period in which your calling thread has no current context, then you would have issues with state tracking. But in this code, I see no such situation.

Getting to your question about which function is valid, I am leaning towards ***neither***.

This is because some other part of your application may have changed the currently bound texture between the time you called `InitializeTextureObject (...)` and `updataTextureObject (...)`. At the very least you need to bind your texture before attempting to issue `glTexSubImage2D (...)`.

There is an extension called Direct State Access that avoids the nightmare of having to bind most OpenGL objects to modify their state. This is probably too advanced for you right now, but it is something to consider in the future. OpenGL's bind-then-modify design is quite frustrating at times.

Comment: yes you're right. I'm just new to OpenGL so too early for me to use extensions like `Direct State Access` but a question rose up! this program is written for high resolution geotiff satellite image and I'm searching for ways to have optimum load on RAM as I develope the code. I meen the performance is important for me. So Do you think binding texture or setting the parameters again will affect performance of the code considering the aspect of how much RAM is used?

Comment: I highly doubt that redundant binds or state changes will impact your performance on a modern computer. A good driver will know when no actual work needs to be done, and the only real performance impact would be minor call overhead from unnecessary API calls.